# What is the difference in case of intent and application between these two Patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, factory, abstract-factory, factory-method

Factory and Abstract Factory are both creational patterns.

What is the difference in case of intent and application between these two Patterns?

Comment: In my opinion the quality of answers in [Differences between Abstract Factory Pattern and Factory Method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5739611/236871) are way better than the ones here.

Comment: The key difference is that Factory Method uses inheritance (indirection is vertical e.g. `createThing()`) and Abstract Factory uses composition (indirection is horizontal e.g. `getFactory().createThing()` )

Comment: This question is not what some of its answerers think it is. Don't miss [Tengiz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27572234/634576), which defines the three distinct terms Factory, Abstract Factory and Factory Method.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Many people will feel surprised maybe, but this question is **incorrect**. If you hear this question during an interview, you need to help the interviewer understand where the confusion is.

Let's start from the fact that there is no concrete pattern that is called just "Factory". There is pattern that is called "Abstract Factory", and there is pattern that is called "Factory Method".

So, what does "Factory" mean then? one of the following (all can be considered correct, depending on the scope of the reference):

- Some people use it as an alias (shortcut) for "[Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)".
- Some people use it as an alias (shortcut) for "[Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)".
- Some people use it as a more general name for all factory/creational patterns. E.g. both "Abstract Factory" and "Factory Method" are Factories.

And, **unfortunately**, many people use "Factory" to denote another kind of factory, that creates factory or factories (or their interfaces). Based on their theory:

> Product implements IProduct, which is created by Factory, which
>   implements IFactory, which is created by AbstractFactory.

To understand how silly this is, let's continue our equation:

> AbstractFactory implements IAbstractFactory, which is created by...
>   AbstractAbstractFactory???

I hope you see the point. Don't get confused, and please don't invent things that don't exist for reason.

-

**P.S.**: Factory for Products is AbstractFactory, and Factory for Abstract Factories would be just another example of AbstractFactory as well.

Comment: how could I differentiate AbstractFactory which creates other AbstractFactories, from AbstractFactory which creates specific objects? GenericAbstractFactory ? Or AbstractFactoryFactory?

Comment: There is no such thing in the design patterns. Both them are instances of AbstractFactory pattern. So, one AbstractFactory creates specific objects, and another AbstractFactory creates factories (which are AbstractFactory again).

Comment: Sure. So how do I name these classes, which do different things? Because creating other factories and creating other (simple) objects are two different things. I don't care about patterns, I need readable code.

Comment: Readable code is the intention revealing code. When naming classes you should not mention too many patterns, unless very necessary. e.g. if you have an abstract factory that creates different transports, maybe call it TransportCreator or TransportFactory, or maybe even TransportManufacturer. And then, if you have factory of these factories, you can call it whatever that is - whoever opens new manufacturers. Maybe that can be ManufacturerManagement? basically, name things as your business calls them, and NOT based on what patterns they implement.

Answer (score 448):

With the Factory pattern, you produce instances of implementations (`Apple`, `Banana`, `Cherry`, etc.) of a particular interface -- say, `IFruit`.

With the Abstract Factory pattern, you provide a way for anyone to provide their own factory. This allows your warehouse to be either an `IFruitFactory` or an `IJuiceFactory`, without requiring your warehouse to know anything about fruits or juices.

Comment: @John,Does a factory necessarily have to produce implementations of an interface? Can it not exist as a standalone concrete class that doesn't need to implement an interface?

Comment: @SPI I think you misunderstand me; the Factory itself doesn't need to implement `IFruit` -- it instantiates things which implement `IFruit`. Of course, it doesn't _need_ to produce instances of things that implement a particular interface, but it's probably a code smell if you have a Factory that produces things which are totally unrelated to each other.

Comment: @John, thanks for clearing it up! For a few hours my entire belief system was shaken up haha Can't help but agree with you about the code smell; it would sort of defeat the purpose of production via factory if the products weren't related to each other wouldn't it?

Comment: Factory that produces Factories. We Need To Go Deeper...

Comment: Never heard of anything more incorrect than this. What would you call a factory that produces interfaces of abstract factories (IAbstractFactory)? - ah I see, that would be AbstractAbstractFactory...

Comment: @tengiz In which cases would you need to do that?

Comment: @joaquin For example, when you need to have factory of IFruitFactory. And as I already mentioned, this is completely incorrect, and is just a result of the confusion about patterns. My answer below clarifies - there is Abstract Factory pattern, then there is Factory Method pattern, and then there are confused people who think Abstract Factory means factory of other factories. Factory is just a generic term used to denote any of the existing patterns. See my answer below for more details if needed.

Comment: This answer it just plain wrong! According to this [GoF book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), an [*abstract factory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) is a factory object that implements a factory interface, so that the concrete factory can be swapped for another subclass. It has nothing to do with *creating* factories. Please remove this answer, it is misleading and confusing people!

Comment: @Paul Annekov an Abstact Factory is not a Factory that produces Factories, it's an interface whose implementations are Factories (that produce products).

Comment: This sounds like an antipattern.

Answer (score 153):

> Source for this information taken from: http://java.dzone.com/news/intro-design-patterns-abstract

### Abstract Factory vs. Factory Method

The methods of an Abstract Factory are implemented as Factory Methods. Both the Abstract Factory Pattern and the Factory Method Pattern decouples the client system from the actual implementation classes through the abstract types and factories.
The Factory Method creates objects through inheritance where the Abstract Factory creates objects through composition.

The Abstract Factory Pattern consists of an AbstractFactory, ConcreteFactory, AbstractProduct, ConcreteProduct and Client.

### How to implement

The Abstract Factory Pattern can be implemented using the Factory Method Pattern, Prototype Pattern or the Singleton Pattern. The ConcreteFactory object can be implemented as a  Singleton as only one instance of the ConcreteFactory object is needed.

Factory Method pattern is a simplified version of Abstract Factory pattern. Factory Method pattern is responsible for creating products that belong to one family, while Abstract Factory pattern deals with multiple families of products.

Factory Method uses interfaces and abstract classes to decouple the client from the generator class and the resulting products. Abstract Factory has a generator that is a container for several factory methods, along with interfaces decoupling the client from the generator and the products.

### When to Use the Factory Method Pattern

Use the Factory Method pattern when there is a need to decouple a client from a particular product that it uses. Use the Factory Method to relieve a client of responsibility for creating and configuring instances of a product.

### When to Use the Abstract Factory Pattern

Use the Abstract Factory pattern when clients must be decoupled from product classes.
Especially useful for program configuration and modification. The Abstract Factory pattern can also enforce constraints about which classes must be used with others. It may be a lot of work to make new concrete factories.

### Examples:

#### Abstract Factory Example 1

This specification for the disks to prepare different types of pasta
in a pasta maker is the Abstract Factory, and each specific disk is a Factory.
all Factories (pasta maker disks) inherit their properties from the abstract Factory.
Each individual disk contains the information of how to create the pasta, and the pasta maker does not.

#### Abstract Factory Example 2:

The Stamping Equipment corresponds to the Abstract Factory, as it is an
interface for operations that create abstract product objects.
The dies correspond to the Concrete Factory, as they create a concrete product.
Each part category (Hood, Door, etc.) corresponds to the abstract product.
Specific parts (i.e., driver side door for 99 camry) corresponds to
the concrete products.

#### Factory Method Example:

The  toy company corresponds to the Creator, since it may use the factory to create product objects. The division of the toy company that manufactures a specific type of toy (horse or car) corresponds to the ConcreteCreator.

Comment: Thanks for the explaining Abstract Factory and Factory Method. I didn't understand where we use composition in abstract factory for creation of objects and where we use inheritance in factory method. It will be very useful if you post some code to explain these. Thank you very much. waiting for your code. Thanks again.

Comment: same here, It would be much more clear if composition and inheritance approaches are shown with a brief example (source code).

Comment: Example code @http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory

Comment: composition example:

public class Client {

 AbstractProduct product;
 AbstractProductAccessories accessories;

 public Client(AbstractFactory factory) {
  AbstractProduct product = factory.createProduct();
 }

 public void run() {
  product.print();
  accessories = product.getAccessories();
 }

}

Comment: Is it possible to detect in code which of this two patterns was used?

Answer (score 105):

Factory pattern:
The factory produces IProduct-implementations

Abstract Factory Pattern:
A factory-factory produces IFactories, which in turn produces IProducts :)

*[Update according to the comments]*
What I wrote earlier is not correct according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) at least. An abstract factory is simply a factory interface. With it, you can switch your factories at runtime, to allow different factories in different contexts. Examples could be different factories for different OS'es, SQL providers, middleware-drivers etc..

Comment: Nice! Is it correct to say that the Abstract Factory is a set of Factory Methods?

Comment: I guess it would be correct, but it would also miss the point :) A non-analogous example could be a FileFactory which had methods such as CreateBitmapFile() or CreateTextFile(). Now, you will pass a reference to that factory into some sort of service. But what would happen once you want to test your service? You would have to create a IFileFactory interface, to mock away access to the file system. Now, in the real world, you would probably have a DI/IoC framework that would instantiate IFileFactories depending on your needs. In this case the IoC framework would serve as the abstract factory.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, this answer seems to imply that the Abstract Factory always *produces* further IFactories, which can in turn be used to create IProducts. The presentation in the GoF does not appear to me to support this, and in fact contradicts it: an instance of an Abstract Factory directly produces IProducts itself.  In other words, a GoF Abstract Factory is *not* (or rather, *need not be*) a "factory-factory".

Comment: The definition of the Abstract Factory Pattern is incorrect. An abstract factory contains one or more factory methods, each producing an instance from the same object family (not to be confused with object hierarchy). While an abstract factory _can_ be a factory of factories, it doesn't have to be one. It is a producer of related products.

Comment: This answer it just plain wrong! According to this [GoF book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), an [*abstract factory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) is a factory object that implements a factory interface, so that the concrete factory can be swapped for another subclass. It has nothing to do with *creating* factories. Please remove this answer, it is misleading and confusing people!

Answer (score 44):

## The Abstract Factory Pattern

- Provide an interface for creating
  families of related or dependent
  objects without specifying their
  concrete classes.
- The Abstract Factory pattern is very
  similar to the Factory Method
  pattern. One difference between the
  two is that with the Abstract Factory
  pattern, a class delegates the
  responsibility of object
  instantiation to another object via
  composition whereas the Factory
  Method pattern uses inheritance and
  relies on a subclass to handle the
  desired object instantiation.
- Actually, the delegated object
  frequently uses factory methods to
  perform the instantiation!

## Factory pattern

- Factory patterns are examples of
  creational patterns
- Creational patterns abstract the
  object instantiation process. They
  hide how objects are created and help
  make the overall system independent
  of how its objects are created and
  composed.
- Class creational patterns focus on
  the use of inheritance to decide the
  object to be instantiated
  Factory Method
- Object creational patterns focus on
  the delegation of the instantiation
  to another object
  Abstract Factory

Reference:
[**Factory vs Abstract Factory**](http://userpages.umbc.edu/%7Etarr/dp/lectures/Factory.pdf)

Comment: reference link is dead

Answer (score 42):

**Basic difference:**

***Factory:*** Creates objects without exposing the instantiation logic to the client.

***Factory Method***: Define an interface for creating an object, but let the subclasses decide which class to instantiate.

***Abstract Factory***: Provides an interface for creating families of related objects

*AbstractFactory* pattern uses composition to delegate responsibility of object creation.

*Factory method* pattern uses inheritance and for derived class  to create object

*Example: StaticFactory*

```
 public class VehicleFactory {

   //Vehicle factory
   public static Vehicle getVehicle(String type){
      if(type == null){
         return null;
      }     
      if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Car")){
         return new Car();
         
      } else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Truck")){
         return new Truck();
         
      } else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Bicycle")){
         return new Bicycle();
      }
      
      return null;
   }
}
```

**When to use:** Client just need a class and does not care about which concrete implementation it is getting.

**Factory Method**

**When to use:** Client doesn't know what concrete classes it will be required to create at runtime, but just wants to get a class that will do the job.

**Abstract Factory**

**When to use:** When your system has to create multiple families of products without exposing the implementation details.

Answer (score 41):

**Factory method:** You have a factory that creates objects that derive from a particular base class

**Abstract factory:** You have a factory that creates *other factories*, and these factories in turn create objects derived from base classes. You do this because you often don't just want to create a single object (as with Factory method) - rather, you want to create a collection of related objects.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the accepted answer, and is equally incorrect.

Answer (score 37):

Abstract factory is an interface for creating related objects but factory method is a method. Abstract factory is implemented by factory method.

[image]

Comment: The second caption in the diagram should read, "these two _may be_ factory methods". Without seeing the implementations, we don't know whether they adhere to the Factory Method pattern or not. It is a common misconception that the methods of an Abstract Factory are automatically Factory Methods. This is not true. There are two separate GoF patterns for a reason: they are implemented differently.

Answer (score 23):

Example/Scenario for Abstract Factory

I live in a place where it rains in the rainy season, snows in winter and hot and sunny in summers. I need different kind of clothes to protect myself from the elements. To do so I go to the store near my house and ask for clothing/items to protect myself. The store keeper gives me the appropriate item as per the environment and depth of my pocket. The items he gives me are of same level of quality and price range. Since he is aware of my standards its easy for him to do so. But when a rich guy from across the street comes up with the same requirements he gets an expensive, branded item. One noticeable thing is all the items he gives to me complement each other in term quality, standard and cost. One can say they go with each other. Same is the case with the items this rich guy gets.

So by looking at above scenario, I now appreciate the efficiency of the shop keeper. I can replace this shopkeeper with an Abstract Shop. The items we get with abstract items and me and the rich as perspective clients. All we need is the product/item which suits our needs.

Now I can easily see myself considering an online store which provides a set of services to its numerous clients. Each client belongs to one of the three groups. When a premium group user opens up the site he gets great UI, highly customised advertisement pane,  more options in the menus etc. These same set of features are presented to gold user but the functionality in the menu is less, advertisements are mostly relevent, and slightly less egronomic UI. Last is my kind of user, a ‘free group’ user. I am just served enough so that I do not get offended. The UI is a bare minimum, advertisements are way off track so much so that I do not know what comes in it, lastly the menu has only log out.

If I get a chance to build something like this website I would definitely consider Abstract Factory Pattern.

Abstract Products : Advertisement Pane, Menu, UI painter.
Abstract Factory : Web Store User Experience
Concreate Factory: Premium User Experience, Gold User Experience, General User Experience.

Comment: Nice scenarios of AbstractFactory but you didn't really answered the question, what is the differences between factory and abstract factory.

Answer (score 18):

```
//Abstract factory - Provides interface to create factory of related products
interface PizzaIngredientsFactory{    
   public Dough createDough(); //Will return you family of Dough
   public Clam createClam();   //Will return you family of Clam
   public Sauce createSauce(); //Will return you family of Sauce
}

class NYPizzaIngredientsFactory implements PizzaIngredientsFactory{

   @Override
   public Dough createDough(){
      //create the concrete dough instance that NY uses
      return doughInstance;
   }

   //override other methods
}
```

The text book definitions are already provided by other answers. I thought I would provide an example of it too.

So here the `PizzaIngredientsFactory` is an **abstract factory** as it provides methods to create family of related products.

Note that each method in the Abstract factory is an **Factory method** in itself. Like `createDough()` is in itself a factory method whose concrete implementations will be provided by subclasses like `NYPizzaIngredientsFactory`. So using this each different location can create instances of concrete ingredients that belong to their location.

### Factory Method

> Provides instance of concrete implementation

In the example:
 - `createDough()` - provides concrete implementation for dough. So this is a factory method

### Abstract Factory

> Provides interface to create family of related objects

In the example:
 - `PizzaIngredientsFactory` is an abstract factory as it allows to create a related set of objects like `Dough`, `Clams`, `Sauce`. For creating each family of objects it provides a factory method.

Example from [Head First design patterns](http://www.amazon.in/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124)

Answer (score 6):

By Definition we can drag out the differences of two:

Factory: An interface is used for creating an object, but subclass decides which class to instantiate. The creation of object is done when it is required.

Abstract Factory: Abstract Factory pattern acts as a super-factory which creates other factories. In Abstract Factory pattern an interface is responsible for creating a set of related objects, or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes.

So, in the definitions above we can emphasize on a particular difference. that is, Factory pattern is responsible for creating objects and Abstract Factory is responsible for creating a set of related objects; obviously both through an interface.

Factory pattern:

```
public interface IFactory{
  void VehicleType(string n);
 }

 public class Scooter : IFactory{
  public void VehicleType(string n){
   Console.WriteLine("Vehicle type: " + n);
  }
 }

 public class Bike : IFactory{
  public void VehicleType(string n) {
  Console.WriteLine("Vehicle type: " + n);
  }
 }

 public interface IVehicleFactory{
  IFactory GetVehicleType(string Vehicle);
 }

 public class ConcreteVehicleFactory : IVehicleFactory{
 public IFactory GetVehicleType(string Vehicle){
   switch (Vehicle){
    case "Scooter":
     return new Scooter();
    case "Bike":
     return new Bike();
    default:
    return new Scooter();
  }
 }

 class Program{
  static void Main(string[] args){
   IVehicleFactory factory = new ConcreteVehicleFactory();
   IFactory scooter = factory.GetVehicleType("Scooter");
   scooter.VehicleType("Scooter");

   IFactory bike = factory.GetVehicleType("Bike");
   bike.VehicleType("Bike");

   Console.ReadKey();
 }
}
```

Abstract Factory Pattern:

```
interface IVehicleFactory{
 IBike GetBike();
 IScooter GetScooter();
}

class HondaFactory : IVehicleFactory{
     public IBike GetBike(){
            return new FZS();
     }
     public IScooter GetScooter(){
            return new FZscooter();
     }
 }
class HeroFactory: IVehicleFactory{
      public IBike GetBike(){
            return new Pulsur();
     }
      public IScooter GetScooter(){
            return new PulsurScooter();
     }
}

interface IBike
    {
        string Name();
    }
interface IScooter
    {
        string Name();
    }

class FZS:IBike{
   public string Name(){
     return "FZS";
   }
}
class Pulsur:IBike{
   public string Name(){
     return "Pulsur";
   }
}

class FZscooter:IScooter {
  public string Name(){
     return "FZscooter";
   }
}

class PulsurScooter:IScooter{
  public string Name(){
     return "PulsurScooter";
   }
}

enum MANUFACTURERS
{
    HONDA,
    HERO
}

class VehicleTypeCheck{
        IBike bike;
        IScooter scooter;
        IVehicleFactory factory;
        MANUFACTURERS manu;

        public VehicleTypeCheck(MANUFACTURERS m){
            manu = m;
        }

        public void CheckProducts()
        {
            switch (manu){
                case MANUFACTURERS.HONDA:
                    factory = new HondaFactory();
                    break;
                case MANUFACTURERS.HERO:
                    factory = new HeroFactory();
                    break;
            }

      Console.WriteLine("Bike: " + factory.GetBike().Name() + "\nScooter: " +      factory.GetScooter().Name());
        }
  }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VehicleTypeCheck chk = new VehicleTypeCheck(MANUFACTURERS.HONDA);
            chk.CheckProducts();

            chk= new VehicleTypeCheck(MANUFACTURERS.HERO);
            chk.CheckProducts();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

My sources are : `StackOverflow`,  `tutorialspoint.com`, `programmers.stackexchange.com` and `CodeProject.com`.

---

`Factory Method` (also called `Factory`) is for decouple client of a `Interface` implementation. For sample we have a `Shape` interface with two `Circle` and `Square` implementations. We have define a factory class with a factory method with a determiner parameter such as `Type` and new related implementation of `Shape` interface.

---

`Abstract Factory` contains several factory method or a factory interface by several factory implementations.
For next above sample we have a `Color` interface with two `Red` and `Yellow` implementations.
We have define a `ShapeColorFactory` interface with two `RedCircleFactory` and `YellowSquareFactory`. Following  code for explain this concept:

```
interface ShapeColorFactory
{
    public Shape getShape();
    public Color getColor();
}

class RedCircleFactory implements ShapeColorFactory
{
    @Override
    public Shape getShape() {
        return new Circle();
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return new Red();
    }
}
class YellowSquareFactory implements ShapeColorFactory
{
    @Override
    public Shape getShape() {
        return new Square();
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return new Yellow();
    }
}
```

Here difference between `FactoryMethod` and `AbstractFactory`. `Factory Method` as simply return a concrete class of a interface but `Abstract Factory` return `factory of factory`. In other words `Abstract Factory` return different combine of a series of interface.

---

I hope my explanation useful.

Answer (score 5):

I have some points to contribute with John's answer as follows:

### Abstract factory is a factory of factories!

With the "Factory Method" (because just "Factory" is ambiguous), you produce implementations (`Lemon`, `Orange`, etc.) of a particular interface -- say, `IFruit`. This Factory could be called `CitricFruitFactory`.

But now you want to create another kinds of fruit that the CitricFruitFactory is not able to create. Maybe the code of `CitricFruitFactory` wouldn't make sense if you create an `Strawberry` in it (strawberry is not a citric fruit!).

So you could create a new Factory called `RedFruitFactory` that produces `Strawberry`, `Raspberry`, etc.

**Like John Feminella said:**
*"With the Abstract Factory pattern, you produce implementations of a particular Factory interface -- e.g., `IFruitFactory`. Each of those knows how to create different kinds of fruit."*

That implementatios of `IFruitFactory` are `CitricFruitFactory` and `RedFruitFactory`!

Answer (score 3):

The major difference in those factories is when what you want to do with the factories and when you want to use it.

Sometimes, when you are doing IOC (inversion of control e.g. constructor injection), you know that you can create solid objects. As mentioned in the example above of fruits, if you are ready to create objects of fruits, you can use simple **factory pattern**.

But many times, you do not want to create solid objects, they will come later in the program flow. But the configuration tells you the what kind of factory you want to use at start, instead of creating objects, you can pass on factories which are derived from a common factory class to the constructor in IOC.

So, I think its also about the object lifetime and creation.

Answer (score 3):

**Extending John Feminella answer:**

`Apple`, `Banana`, `Cherry` implements `FruitFactory` and that has a method called `Create` which is solely responsible of creating Apple or Banana or Cherry. You're done, with your `Factory` method.

Now, you want to `Create` a special salad out of your fruits and there comes your **Abstract Factory**. Abstract Factory knows how to create your special Salad out of the Apple, Banana and Cherry.

```
public class Apple implements Fruit, FruitFactory {
    public Fruit Create() {
        // Apple creation logic goes here
    }
}

public class Banana implements Fruit, FruitFactory {
    public Fruit Create() {
        // Banana creation logic goes here
    }
}

public class Cherry implements Fruit, FruitFactory {
    public Fruit Create() {
        // Cherry creation logic goes here
    }
}

public class SpecialSalad implements Salad, SaladFactory {
    public static Salad Create(FruitFactory[] fruits) {
        // loop through the factory and create the fruits.
        // then you're ready to cut and slice your fruits 
        // to create your special salad.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `Factory Method` and `Abstract Factory` keep the clients decoupled from the concrete types. Both create objects, but `Factory` method uses inheritance whereas `Abstract Factory` use composition.

The `Factory Method` is inherited in subclasses to create the concrete objects(products) whereas `Abstract Factory` provide interface for creating the family of related products and subclass of these interface define how to create related products.

Then these subclasses when instantiated is passed into product classes where it is used as abstract type. The related products in an `Abstract Factory` are often implemented using `Factory Method`.

Answer (score 1):

Check here: http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/abstract_factory_pattern.htm
it seems that Factory method uses a particular class(not abstract) as a base class while Abstract factory uses an abstract class for this. Also if using an interface instead of abstract class the result will be a different implementation of Abstract Factory pattern.

:D

Answer (score 1):

Abstract Factory is template for creating different type of interfaces.
Suppose you have project that requires you to parse different types of csv files containing quantity, price and item specific information like some contain data about fruits other about chocolates and then after parsing you need to update this information in their corresponding database so now you can have one abstract factory returning you parser and modifier factory and then this parser factory can return you Chocolate parser object,Fruit Parser Object etc. and similarly Modifier Factory can return Chocolate modifier object , Fruit Modifier object etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can understand the difference between these two by seeing a Java8 example code:

```
  interface Something{}

  interface OneWhoCanProvideSomething {
     Something getSomething();
  }

  interface OneWhoCanProvideCreatorsOfSomething{
     OneWhoCanProvideSomething getCreator();
  }


public class AbstractFactoryExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //I need something
        //Let's create one
        Something something = new Something() {};

        //Or ask someone (FACTORY pattern)
        OneWhoCanProvideSomething oneWhoCanProvideSomethingOfTypeA = () -> null;
        OneWhoCanProvideSomething oneWhoCanProvideSomethingOfTypeB = () -> null;

        //Or ask someone who knows soemone who can create something (ABSTRACT FACTORY pattern)
        OneWhoCanProvideCreatorsOfSomething oneWhoCanProvideCreatorsOfSomething = () -> null;

        //Same thing, but you don't need to write you own interfaces
        Supplier<Something> supplierOfSomething = () -> null;
        Supplier<Supplier<Something>> supplierOfSupplier = () -> null;
    }

}
```

Now the question is which way of creation should you use and why:
The first way (no pattern, just plain constructor): creating by yourself is not a good idea, you have to do all the work, and your client code is tied to the particular implementation.

The second way (using Factory pattern): provides you the benefit that you can pass any type of implementation, which can provide different type of something based on some condition (maybe a parameter passed to creational method).

The third way (using Abstract Factory pattern): This gives you more flexibility. You can find different types of creators of something based on some condition (maybe a parameter passed).

***Note that you can always get away with Factory pattern by combining two conditions together (which slightly increases code complexity, and coupling), I guess that's why we rarely see real life use cases of Abstract Factory pattern.***