# example of factory pattern in java jdk

Tags: factory-pattern

At below link:
[Examples of GoF Design Patterns in Java's core libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)
that java.lang.Object#toString() is example of factory pattern.
I am confused about this.
What i have understood till now is that factory pattern is used to create objects .
Can someone explain it more clearly?

Comment: Seems like a weak example to me.

Comment: @Bill..Yes, that's why I wanted to be clear whether something I am not getting or this example itself is not correct. Can you provide a strong example in jdk?

Comment: Yes, the Factory pattern is very generic... which is why GoF only lists "Factory method" and "Abstract Factory", no generic "Factory" pattern ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Factory, Abstract Factory and Factory Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079902/factory-abstract-factory-and-factory-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence, the factory pattern is an abstract class or interface that specifies a method to produce *something*. Then you have an implementation and from that implementation, you can build that *something*.

Here we have:

Abstract class or interface: Object

Build method: toString()

Implementation: Any java object

Product: A string

So yeah, it is a bit of a strange example and there are better ones out there, but it does fit the model for a factory.

Comment: then in that case..any method of any interface, except having void return type can be classified as factory pattern.. right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. That's pretty much why I think it's a silly example.

Answer (score 2):

Factory design pattern is used when we have a super class with multiple sub-classes and based on input, we need to return one of the sub-class. Typically, getInstance() method is present which returns different type of objects based on inputs provided.
To understand it better, You can refer this example, in Java API-  calender class returns different calender object based on inputs :

```
static Calendar getInstance()
Gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale.

static Calendar getInstance(Locale aLocale)
Gets a calendar using the default time zone and specified locale.

static Calendar getInstance(TimeZone zone)
Gets a calendar using the specified time zone and default locale.

static Calendar getInstance(TimeZone zone, Locale aLocale)
Gets a calendar with the specified time zone and locale.
```

Examples of Factory pattern used in JDK:

`java.util.Calendar, ResourceBundle and NumberFormat getInstance() methods`