# Can a 'Factory' Design Pattern have more than 1 abstract type in a factory?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

Please note; Factory, not Abstract Factory.

Say, there is an ***interface*** `Shape` with concrete classes like `Pentagon`. Let's say an ***abstract class*** `Quadrilateral` implements `Shape` and has its own concrete types like `Square`.

Is this still considered a Factory Method?

Comment: If you're asking whether a single class can have more than one Factory Method in it, the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but could you clarify? @jaco0646

Comment: What I'm asking is: referring to the e.g. [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm), `shape` is an interface; if it also has an abstract class called `quadrilateral` with its own implementations, would that diagram still be a Factory Pattern?

Comment: @AMoses the factory will create a new instance of Square, so yes it is still Factory Pattern. The abstract class Quadrilateral can never be instantiated.

Comment: @AMoses What you are looking for is abstract factory pattern which is available in the same site
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm

When you want to decouple the creation of a family of objects of a similar kind (like in your case, where Shape is the most generic and Quadrilateral or Circle based are a family), you use abstract factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the `Shape` interface represents the *product* created by the factory. So long as the factory returns `Shape` instances, any other details of the product inheritance hierarchy are irrelevant to both the factory and its clients.

Secondly, the tutorial linked in the comment describes what Head First Design Patterns calls a *Simple Factory*. It is not a GoF design pattern. You can read my take on the GoF patterns [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50786084/1371329).

Finally, a warning: beware any blog or tutorial using the phrase "Factory Pattern". There is no single pattern named "Factory". Factory is a category of patterns including instances both inside and outside the GoF book. There are at least four factory patterns in common use.

Comment: Answered the question, then some more. Thanks for clarifying why internet examples implemented 'Factory Method' differently; some are actually 'Simple Factory'.

Comment: This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209791/design-patterns-abstract-factory-vs-factory-method/38668246#38668246), referred by @jaco0646 in another answer of his, helped a ton too.