# How to initialize an instance of a class to set properties given the value of a variable assigned in a constructor?

Tags: c#

I am curious about the best C# practice for the following scenario:

I have a class called `Platform` which contains a constructor that allows for a single argument called `platformName`. I would like to create an instance of an object that populates the instance with properties related to that variable name. For example...I want to create an instance of a class like so:

`var spotify = new Platform("PlatformName_Spotify");`

When this is instantiated, it sets properties related to Spotify (such as its brand color, its slogan, and monthly users) so that I can access them like:

`spotify.color or spotify.slogan or spotify.monthlyUsers`

Is it best to make dictionaries of each brand inside the `Platform` class and then assign the dictionary to the matching variable name that is passed? This is what I came up with, but I feel like there has to be a better way! How would you accomplish this?

```
public class Platform
{

    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> spotify = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "color", "green" },
        { "slogan", "Music For Everyone" },
        { "monthlyUsers", "14M" }
    };

    private readonly string color;
    private readonly string slogan;
    private readonly string monthlyUsers;

    public Platform(string platformName)
    {
        if(platformName == "PlatformName_Spotify")
        {
            this.color = spotify["color"];
            this.slogan = spotify["slogan"];
            this.monthlyUsers = spotify["monthlyUsers"];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Or just implement the Factory pattern.

Comment: Consider making `Platform` `abstract`. Then create `SpotifyPlatform` that inherits from it and sets whatever it needs to.

Comment: @mjwills almost on track with this one, however, As there will be several platforms (unknown until runtime), I dont think I can do this because I would need to hard code an instantiation of the `SpotifyPlatform` class you mentioned in your comment, right? For a specific page, `PlatformName_Spotify` may not be passed as a constructor argument. (It may be iTunes, SoundCloud, etc)

Comment: `AbstractPlatform`, `SpotifyPlatform`, `ITunesPlatform`, `SoundCloudPlatform`, `GenericPlatformWhereICanPassParametersIfIWantTo` etc etc.

Comment: Not sure how useful the dictionary is based on your comment. The example would require you to either have specialized classes for the platforms or allow passing the dictionary in.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils looks like factory pattern is what I should be using as I don't know what classes to instantiate until runtime, hmm

Comment: Is the dictionary hard coded?

Comment: @shingo yes, the platforms are hardcoded as dictionaries, but the decision of which one to instantiate is not defined until runtime

Comment: These properties look like changeable, anyway usually I will use a config file.

Comment: [What is the basic difference between the Factory and Abstract Factory Design Patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35714637/7444103) (don't consider the accepted answer). -- [Design Patterns: Abstract Factory vs Factory Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211307/7444103).